# Largest card size for board games

Tags: components

What's the largest card size in a board game that's still current (in print sometime in the 21st century)?

I'm looking for cards that are used as *cards*, not as placemats.  This means that the cards are used in a deck or a pile containing multiple cards at a time.

(A good answer would be in both inches and millimeters.)

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: @PatLudwig, I design board games for a company that's interested in keeping an eye on card sizes in the marketplace.

Comment: The Great Project cards in 7 Wonders: Babel are huge. You only use 1 at a time and they're essentially placemats, but they're cards in that they're designed to be shuffled for randomisation (and not printed as thicker tiles like the wonder boards). I don't know the size exactly but I'll have a check later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This PDF](http://maydaygames.com/sleeves.pdf) from maydaygames.com contains the sizes of cards for just about every modern game.  It looks like the largest one on there is for Planechase at 89mm x 127mm (3.5" x 5").

Comment: I'm surprised something beat out Dixit.